# Delphi, TActionToolBar without shortcut (Delphi XE)

Tags: delphi, shortcut

How to disable underline letter in captions at ActionToolBar items? I disabled shortcuts (showshortcut=false), deleted '&' letters in captions and in design mode undreline letters disapear but in run mode them bring back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete '&' letters AND disable the option "AutoHotKeys" in your TActionClients component (TActionManager -> ActionBars -> Items -> AutoHotKeys).